# ApplicationSettings not binding to properties when type is StringCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, windows-forms-designer, application-settings

I'm working in C# winforms, and I would like the following behavior:

Define a list of strings inside applicationsettings, and then bind them to a property in my form.

I was able to do this with a string (not a list) without much problem.  I defined my string in the settings file, opened the designer, went to (ApplicationSettings), and added the binding.

To do this with a bunch of string, I started by making a StringCollection as my settings type, which seemed to work fine.  I then created a property of the same type (StringCollection).

In the designer, that property is not selectable at all, and I'm not sure why.  It doesn't show up in the list of available properties to bind to.

Do I need some special attributes on my property to get the binding to work?  Am I using the wrong datatype for my application settings?

To Clarify: All my properties are showing up correctly in my form designer.  The specific problem I'm having is this, once the designer is loaded, I'm attempting to bind a property of type StringCollection to an ApplicationResource, via the (Application Settings) part of the property grid.  Attempting to select my property from that list is where all my custom "String" properties are showing up, but properties of type "StringCollection" are not.

Comment: Binding to a StringCollection is a very different problem than getting your collection properties to show up the WinForms designer. Did you test binding your data by putting the string collection to the binding source? Try wrapping it in a BindingList? If that works, clarify your question.

Comment: I added some information to the bottom of my question, I'm not sure how your answer applies to my issue.  Would my resource file have type StringCollection, and then bind it a BindingSource Property in my form which is then bound to my stringcollection property of my form?